# Unable to create native player - Unspported format

Tags: java, java-me

Good afternoon,

I'm working with Video API in J2ME (SDK 3.4), but i have a problem in my code "Unable to create native player" with "MP4, 3GP" and
Unsupported format "MPEG" when i use mpg or mpeg files. there is my code

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package videosup;

import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.media.Manager;
import javax.microedition.media.Player;
import javax.microedition.media.control.VideoControl;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

/**
 * @author Chaabouni
 */
public class Midlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener{
    Display disp;
    Form fmMain;
    Command cmExit;
    StringItem Msg;
    Player p;
    VideoControl vc;
    public Midlet()
    {
        disp = Display.getDisplay(this);
        cmExit = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 1);
        fmMain = new Form("Hello Video");
        Msg = new StringItem("", "Hello video");
        fmMain.addCommand(cmExit);
        fmMain.append(Msg);
        fmMain.setCommandListener(this);
    }
    public void startApp() {
        try {
            InputStream dt = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/videosup/1.3gp");
            p = Manager.createPlayer(dt, "video/3gp");
            p.realize();
            vc = (VideoControl)p.getControl("VideoControl");
            if(vc != null)
            {
                fmMain.append((Item)vc.initDisplayMode(vc.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, null));
                Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(fmMain);
            }
            p.prefetch();
            p.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
        try {
            p.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        p = null;
    }

    public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
        if(c == cmExit)
        {
            destroyApp(false);
            notifyDestroyed();
        }
    }
}
```

when i change

```
InputStream dt = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/videosup/1.3gp");
            p = Manager.createPlayer(dt, "video/3gp");
```

by

```
InputStream dt = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/videosup/1.mp4");
            p = Manager.createPlayer(dt, "video/mp4");
```

i have "unable to create native player.

when i use 
`InputStream dt = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/videosup/1.mpg");
            p = Manager.createPlayer(dt, "video/mpeg");`
i have "Unsupported mpeg format"
so my question is ? why i have this problem ? and how can i fix it ?
Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/969193/1284073

Comment: I didn't get it how can i test the potential of my device i use ther default configuration of the 3.4 SDK JavaME

Comment: Check the video.encodings system property. What does it have?

Comment: I have Malformed locator

Comment: Did you use System.out.println(System.getProperty("video.encodings")) ?

Comment: Yes ! and it says Malformed locator

Comment: Can you try on a different device or simulator?

Comment: No, and i don't have physical device to test on it :/